# Scrape "valorinveste.globo.com" with Selenium leads to ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some news titles and links from the website https://valorinveste.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/ but to load more news is needed to click in a Load More button ("Veja Mais" in purple at the bottom of the news) but the site have a notifications window that randomly appears and its also have some ads that load as you scroll the page.

[image]

My code work most of the time, but in some cases the time to load and show the ads will show the button under the random notification window. I tried to wait for the notification but it was in vain, as it load when you scroll.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

driver.get(https://valorinveste.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='cookie-banner-lgpd_accept-button']")))
consent.click

for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(6):
        load_more = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='load-more gui-color-primary-bg']//a")))
        dates = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='feed-post-datetime']")))
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', dates[-1])
        wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(load_more)
    load_more.click()

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to listen for all elements that are loaded and if element has modal id (or other unique attribute that points to it), assign `display: none` property to it.

It can be done before you're getting site url by `execute_cdp_cmd` driver method, when you perform evaluate script on new document as first option
and listen to event `DOMNodeInserted`.

In the code below I listen if elements doesn't have id of your modal from screenshot and for google ads banner (both of them can intercept your click).

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument",{'source': """
            document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
                let element = event.target;
                if (element.id === 'onesignal-slidedown-dialog' || element.id?.includes('google_ads_iframe')) { 
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
"""})
driver.get('https://valorinveste.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/')
# your further code
```

Comment: I tried your code but Im getting a StaleElementReferenceException randomly when scraping the page, it already occurred at 27, 32 and 52 loop iteration, can you help in this case?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoBarros what is the code that you are using? Provided example from question doesn't have 27 loop iterations.

I guess random pop-ups is not your only issue.

Comment: I changed the range value at the outer for loop, to scroll more times and scrape more news, tried 60 loops, but the average that I get before the error is 25-27 loops